# Trigonometry with Java

Tags: java, android, math, libgdx, trigonometry

I'm trying to do some basic trigonometry with Java and LibGDX on android.
I've spent a long time googling "How to find an angle in right triangles".
I still don't really understand :(

I want to give an Actor subclass a random direction to follow. So what is the angle - and what should I set xSpeed and ySpeed to, in order to move at the correct angle.

I started writing an app to help me see how it works.

There are two objects - An origin point and a touch point. User presses screen, touchPoint moves to where user touched. Methods fire to figure out the appropriate values. I know the XDistance and YDistance between the two points. That means I know the Opposite length and the Adjacent length. So all I need to do is tan-1 of (opposite / adjacent), am I right?

I just don't understand what to do with the numbers my program spits out.

Some code:

In create event of main class:

```
stage.addListener(new ClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            touchPoint.setX(x);
            touchPoint.setY(y);
            touchPoint.checkDistance(); // saves x and y distances from origin in private fields
            atan2D = getAtan2(touchPoint.getYDistance(), touchPoint.getXDistance());
            tanhD = getTanh(touchPoint.getYDistance(), touchPoint.getXDistance());
            xDistanceLbl.setText("X Distance: " + touchPoint.getXDistance());
            yDistanceLbl.setText("Y Distance: " + touchPoint.getYDistance());
            atan2Lbl.setText("Atan2: " + atan2D);
            tanhLbl.setText("Tanh: " + tanhD);
            angleLbl.setText("Angle: No idea");
         }
      })

...

private double getAtan2(float adjacent, float opposite) {
      return Math.atan2(adjacent, opposite);
   }

   private double getTanh(float adjacent, float opposite) {
      return Math.tanh((adjacent / opposite));
   }
```

These two functions give me numbers between (atan2: -pi to pi) and (tanh: -1.0 to 1.0)

How do I turn these values into angles from which I can then work backwards and get the opposite and adjacent again?
Doing this should allow me to create and object with a random direction, which I can use in 2D games.

Comment: Given two vector2s on a 2D plane, one can draw an imaginary right-triangle that connects the two points by checking the distance in two dimensions between the two points. I have a triangle. It's right there.

Comment: Basically, I want to set a random direction for an Actor class to move in. First, I need the angle - then, from that, I should be able to work out how many pixels the object would need to move in x and y directions to achieve the correct angle. Make sense?

Comment: Cool, okay. Now I think there's probably enough info on OP. So any idea what I need to do to progress from here?

Comment: Don't use `tanh` here, I added explanation.

Comment: Yes, thanks MBo. It was very helpful. I had both there to see how they differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atan2` gives you direction in radians. Direction from origin `(0,0)` to `touchPoint`. If you need direction from some object to `touchPoint`, then subtract object coordinates. Perhaps you also want to see direction in degrees (this is only for human eyes)

```
dx = x - o.x
dy = y - o.y
dir = atan2(dy, dx)
dir_in_degrees = 180 * dir / Pi
```

I you have direction and want to retrieve coordinate differences, you need to store distance

```
distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
later
dx = distance * cos(dir) 
dy = distance * sin(dir)
```

But note that often storing `dx` and `dy` is better, because some calculations might be performed without trigonometric functions

---

Just noticed - using `tanh` is completely wrong, this is hyperbolic tangent function, it has no relation to geometry.

You can use `arctan`, but it gives angle in half-range only (compared with `atan2`)